# Splitting string into groups with regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings that can have a various amount of "groups". I need to split them, but I am having trouble doing so. The groups will always start with `[A-Z]{2-5}` followed by a `:` and a string or varying length and spaces. It will always have a space in front of the group.

Example strings:

```
"YellowSky AA:Hello AB:1234 AC:1F 322 AD:hj21jkhjk23"
"Billy Bob Thorton AA:213231 AB:aaaa AC:ddddd 322 AD:hj2ffs   dsfdsfd1jkhjk23"
```

My code thus far:

```py
import re
D = "Test1 AA:Hello AB:1234 AC:1F 322 AD:hj21jkhjk23"
    
g = re.compile("(?<!^)\s+(?=[A-Z])(?!.\s)").split(D)
```

As you can see... this works for one word starting string, but not multiple words.

[image: Works]

But this fails /w spaces:
[image: Doesn't work]

Comment: What is the expected output? Try `(?!^)\s+(?=[A-Z]+:)`, see https://regex101.com/r/QTmjkX/1

Comment: Don't use `split`. Write a regexp that matches the groups, and use `re.findall()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.split(r'(?!^)\s+(?=[A-Z]+:)', text)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QTmjkX/1).

*Details*:

- `(?!^)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location not at the start of string (equal to `(?<!^)` but one char shorter)
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=[A-Z]+:)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more uppercase ASCII letters followed with a `:` char immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 1):

```
([A-Z]{2,5}:\w+(?: +\w+)*)(?=(?: +[A-Z]+:|$))
```

You can also use `re.findall` directly.

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/6jf8EM/1

This way you don't need to filter unwanted groups later. You get what you need.

Comment: Thanks, it does help, though I need to first section too.